# How to run bash scripts with yarn via a separate file?

Tags: bash, yarnpkg

I have a Node/React project and in my **package.json** if I want to run some simple scripts I might do something like this:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "prep": "cp -r this/sub-directory/path another/sub-directory/path"
  },
}
```

And then `yarn prep` to execute it.

However in this case I have a lot of commands, say 5-6 and to put them all on one line in a package.json file would make it difficult to read.

What I would like to do is put them in a separate file and then just call that file. Something like a file named **run-script**:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo 'test'
```

and then in package.json:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "prep": "run-script"
  },
}
```

But that gives me errors obviously, I don't know how to tell it to run the file, what extension it should be, etc. (I'm aware that I can do `"prep": "node run-script.js"` but in this case I want to do simple things like copy directories and such, not JavaScript things.)

---

#### Update [SOLVED]

Both of [@roadowl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2849202/roadowl)’s solutions were needed.

1. Run `chmod ug+x run-script` to set the permissions, and then
2. Add the current working directory variable (`$PWD`) in front of where the file is called in **package.json**:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "prep": "$PWD/run-script"
  },
}
```

Comment: I don't see why that wouldn't work. My only advice would be to call it with its full path, `"/home/me/run-script"`, and of course make sure it's executable by doing `chmod ug+x run-script`.

Comment: That worked! Both of your suggestions were needed — thanks! I'll update the question with the details. (And if you want to put them in an answer I'll accept it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see why that wouldn't work.
My only advice would be to call it with its full path:

```
"prep": "/home/me/run-script"
```

(Where `/home/me' is your home directory, i.e. that which 'echo $HOME' prints).

And, in addition, of course make sure run-script is executable by doing:

```
chmod ug+x run-script
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to set an absolute path, a relative URL works fine, but bear in mind that if you are referring to the same folder, don't forget to prepend './'

For example:

```
"scripts": {
   ...
   "foo": "./foo.sh",
   ...
}
```

Also, as Roadowl suggested, you have to set execution permissions